# Increase SOAP message size in case of a web reference

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-1.1, web-reference

I have a WCF soap service and a .net 1.1 project.

The .net 1.1 project calls the Service (.svc) through a Web Reference. Ideally this should be a service reference but for compatibility issues it has to be like this.

The problem is that my messages can become quite large and I need to increase the message size. In the case of 'add service reference' I would change some parameters in the web.config on the client side but that's not possible with my Web Reference.

How can I increase the allowed soap message size?

This is the exception message: 'The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.'
The exception gets thrown as soon as a certain size has been exceeded.